# ssh into device with wrong (probably) static ip adress

Tags: networking

I have a problem with a remote sensor (connected via a raspberry), it is connected to a local router and correctly uses it as gateway. I can see that the raspberry got an ip address via dhcp. However, there is some configuration mismatch. The raspberry thinks it has a different ip address (probably known to me). Therefore I cannot ping it or ssh into it. Is there still a way to connect to it via ssh ?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you don't know the IP of the RPi? Do you have other devices in this local network? Another Raspberry? If so you can try to run nmap or if you have a smartphone in the network you can use the Fing app on iOS or Android.

Comment: nmap -sP does not find the raspberry. The raspberry displays the ip adress locally on a screen and it is wrong. However, the router has given an ip adress to the device. Probably I have to get the sd card in order to see what is wrong.

Comment: ping should work by default. So I think the chances to connect are very small. Do you have physical access to the RPi or the SD Card?

Comment: I have to go there. Damn.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IP address that the raspberry pi 'thinks' it has: and you have access to the router configuration. Configure the router to allocate the IP that the Pi thinks it has by DHCP fixed/static address to the Pi.  That way both the router and the Pi agree what the address is.  You should then be able to connect. (provided that there are no other network configuration issues: e.g. routing).

Comment: Hah, I will try